# format git output to show files committed in new line with date

Tags: git

I am trying to format `git log` output such that it returns file which were committed along with the date when they were committed. For example. I want my output to look like this:

```
filename.py - date
filename2.py - date
filename3.py - date
```

I know I can format the output using `--pretty` option, but unable to get the output in desired format. I have tried the following command:

```
❯ git --no-pager log --name-only --pretty=format:"%n%cd-" --date=format:"%Y-%m-%d" --diff-filter=A -- rewiser/
```

which returns the output as follows:

```
2023-06-11-
rewiser/gpt/__init__.py
rewiser/gpt/chain.py
rewiser/gpt/examples.py
rewiser/gpt/prompts.py
rewiser/gpt/rough.txt


2023-06-10-
rewiser/__init__.py
rewiser/anki.py
rewiser/email.py
rewiser/files.py
rewiser/utils.py
```

Just wanted to check if my desired output format is possible or not.

Comment: What does "date when they were committed" even mean? Every commit contains every file. Every commit you're showing in the log has a date, and you've obtained that. What else is there to know? It looks to me like you've solved the problem: you're displaying the commit date and the files that changed in that commit.

Comment: Not possible with just `git log` alone. You need to process the output with some other tool (e.g. `sed`) to extract the date line and append it to every following line until the next date line is reached.